# Word that means "a music-band that uses computer-synthesised instruments"

Tags: word-request

Years ago, I read in a newspaper about a band that uses only instruments synthesised by *tablet computers*. They used a particular term for such a band. But now that paper is lost.

Can anybody tell me what word is *used for a music-band that use computer synthesised instrument.*

Comment: Are your referring to techno music?

Comment: Are you thinking of *techno*? It designates a genre rather than a performer, but it can be used as an attributive, "a techno group".

Comment: Any music can be synthesized electronically :)

Comment: Please see my other post http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19303/13550

Comment: that would be 1980s music

Answer (score 1):

Hm, lots of interpretations here.

If you're looking for a genre where the songs are primarily computer-synthesized music, I'd call that "electronic music", but this usually comes with some implicit awareness that you're referring to a particular style of music. e.g., most people think of electronic music along the lines of techno, EDM, chiptune, etc., whereas they might not classify a transcription of "classical music" played in MIDI as electronic music.

If synthesizers are the dominant instrument, I'd call it a "synth band" or a "synthpop band".

I noticed your emphasis on "tablet computers". If you mean tablet computers are necessary to the performance or recording, maybe you mean "Controllerism"? They use tablet computers (along with hacked-together electronic instruments of their own design) to compose and perform music.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllerism

http://mmmmaven.com/2015/02/27/controllerism-a-different-and-interactive-way-to-perform/

Answer (score 1):

In singular I think such a person may be referred to as an ***e-jay***.

(Two or more people may get together on a ***collab*** and generate digital music/video).

Comment: wait... how many years ago?

Answer (score 1):

Such an assembly is often called a [laptop orchestra](https://www.google.com/search?q=laptop+orchestra&ie=UTF-8), particularly when they play avant-garde or experimental music.  Here is an example of a [performance by the Stanford Laptop Orchestra](https://vimeo.com/100624271) and some [interviews with the Princeton Laptop Orchestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOsaANAfZcw).